# Windows equivalent to xargs?

Tags: linux, windows-7, command-line

What would be the Windows 7 Equivalent for the following command?

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/ url \([^" >][^ >]*\)/ url "\1"/g'
```

I am trying to migrate Django 1.4 to 1.5

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think that installing original tools is much better in terms of unification then rewriting everything. I personally use [GOW](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki), it still misses a tiny number of commands but contains all most needed stuff.

If you still want to hit batch programming there's a good list of all commands: http://ss64.com/nt/, I think you need `forfiles`.

Comment: The identical `xargs.exe` can be found in the package `findutils` from the project `GnuWin` ( http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/findutils.htm )

Comment: how to access/run xargs after installing GOW? I'm trying to run a command on a project folder and seems it's still missing

Comment: GoW adds to the Path environment variable so it should be accessible from any cmd/powershell you open after its installed.  If you opened a cmd window before installation that might explain what you're seeing

Answer (score 1):

Copied from [here](https://helloacm.com/simple-xargs-batch-implementation-for-windows/)

```
@echo off
:: example:   git branch | grep -v "develop" | xargs git branch -D
:: example    xargs -a input.txt echo
:: https://helloacm.com/simple-xargs-batch-implementation-for-windows/
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set args=
set file='more'

:: read from file
if "%1" == "-a" (
    if "%2" == "" (
        echo Correct Usage: %0 -a Input.txt command
        goto end
    )
    set file=%2
    shift
    shift
    goto start
)

:: read from stdin
set args=%1
shift

:start
    if [%1] == [] goto start1
    set args=%args% %1
    shift
    goto start

:start1
    for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (!file!) do (
        %args% %%a
    )

:end
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience only [rush](https://github.com/shenwei356/rush) works correctly on Windows - it handles paths with backslashes and allows \r\n as a delimiter. Has native (non cygwin) build, can buffer and sort output.

Answer (score 0):

Minimalist xargs for Windows created using pyinstaller and a short python script is available below:

https://github.com/manasmbellani/xargswin/releases

Answer (score 0):

[TextTools (github.com)](https://github.com/idigdoug/TextTools) includes a Windows-native xargs clone called wargs. It supports nearly all of the GNU xargs functionality, plus options to specify the input text's encoding in case it isn't ASCII.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).